# I keep on getting a lots of error when doing sudo apt-get update. And it take a long time to complete

Tags: debian, error-handling

```
 unique@my-pc ~ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for unique: 

    Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                 
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main i386 Packages                                                                                                                  
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                                                                                                                 
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                 
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main i386 Packages                                                                                                                  
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                                                                                                                 
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                 
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main i386 Packages                                                                                                                  
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                                                                                                                 
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                 
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main i386 Packages                                                                                                                  
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                                                                                                                 
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                 
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main i386 Packages                                                                                                                  
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                                                                                                                 
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                 
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main i386 Packages                                                                                                                  
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                                                                                                                 
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                 
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main i386 Packages                                                                                                                  
  404  Not Found
```

My `sources.list` content follows:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

```
chrome-remote-desktop.list       mutate-ppa-jessie.list                 qos-pulseaudio-dlna-jessie.list       team-xbmc-ppa-jessie.list.save
chrome-remote-desktop.list.save  mutate-ppa-jessie.list.save            qos-pulseaudio-dlna-jessie.list.save  vivaldi.list
easystroke-ppa-jessie.list       nilarimogard-webupd8-jessie.list       saiarcot895-myppa-jessie.list         vivaldi.list.save
easystroke-ppa-jessie.list.save  nilarimogard-webupd8-jessie.list.save  saiarcot895-myppa-jessie.list.save    wine-wine-builds-jessie.list
google-chrome.list               noobslab-themes-jessie.list            spotify.list                          wine-wine-builds-jessie.list.save
google-chrome.list.save          noobslab-themes-jessie.list.save       spotify.list.save
jessie-backports.list.save       numix-ppa-jessie.list                  team-xbmc-ppa-jessie.list
```

I'm confused. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can update my system?

Comment: You've got a ton of stuff in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Go through it and throw out what you don't need. Did you add those files, or were they added by a script? Your errors are saying your URLs don't exist. Check the URLs yourself - you'll find they don't exist.

Comment: Delete **PPA**s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, keep your `sources.list.d` cleaner and delete all unnecessary stuff.

Secondly, why are you using **Personal Package Archives** (**PPA**s)? Don't you use Ubuntu PPAs in Debian distribution, many Launchpad PPAs are not compatible with Debian since the packages are built on Ubuntu libraries.

To remove PPAs, do the following:

```
add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa
```

In addition, there is no need of the `deb-src` line if you don't need it, `deb` lines are relative to binary packages while `deb-src` are to source packages. So you can get rid of it. - if that's not important for you, I personally do not remove them

Meanwhile, **Error 404** is an HTTP status and response code to indicate that the client was able to successfully communicate with the server, but the server could not find whatever that was requested. PPAs are not fully compatible with Debian, I recommend you remove them, and try to have essential repositories.

Here is what you need and should have in your `sources.list.d`, repositories of yours don't exist, so that's why you get **Error 404 Not Found**!

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

If you also want the **contrib** and **non-free components**, add **contrib non-free** after **main**:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: `ppa-purge` is only avaible to Ubuntu's users.

Comment: @GAD3R thanks for mentioning, I removed `ppa-purge` from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove other derivative repositories because they are not compatible with Debian:

Adding a `ppa` will create two files: `your_ppa.list` and `your_ppa.list.save`

1) Delete the `ppa`:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/your_ppa.list
```

Remove `your_ppa.list.save`

```
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/your_ppa.list.save
```

2) remove the trusted key of the repository:

First list the `gpg` key with `apt-key list`

Remove  key from `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` using:

```
sudo apt-key del KEY_ID
```

Update your package : `sudo apt-get udate`

Example:

```
#sudo apt-key list
 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
uid                  Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key)   <info@virtualbox.org>
sub   4096R/920E471F 2016-04-22
```

The key is `920E471F` , to remove it run:

```
sudo apt-key del 920E471F
```